# laravel 5 boilerplate app not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

i am new to laravel framework, as a first ever application with the framework i tried to create a minimal application for that i want to know how can i view the default auth, login, register pages found under routes.php?

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

i can only see the welcome page which is as below,

[image]

```
project hosted directory is E:\xampp\htdocs\directory\app\
```

when i went go to this path, **http://localhost/directory/public/auth/login** i could see the login page but its without any styles, just plain UI like this.

[image]

and there when i click on login button URL is redirecting to somewhere else.

its going here -> **http://localhost/auth/login**

and displaying **Object not found!** error.

what did i miss in my configuration?

UPDATE: It seems like app.blade.php is not loading and that is why pages are in plain text mode without any html styles.

Comment: Did you set write permissions to the storage directory?

Comment: @hfingler i checked the security settings. all users has full control to storage directory

Comment: I don't know how to fix this.. if it was Unix I'd say try setting `777` to the storage folder, don't know how to do this in Windows though.

Comment: open firebug or any equivalent tool to see what is the path of the app.css file, I guess it is a problem with the path of app.css included in app.blade.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the document root to point to your `directory/public` folder.

In this way you will be able to access laravel directly from http://localhost